# curl command not working on server.... any alternate of this?

Tags: javascript, php, sms

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$adm=$_POST["admno"];
$phn=$_POST["phn1"];
include("model.php");
$db = new database;
$r=$db->register($adm);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{

if($row["phn_no1"]==$phn  || $row["phn_no2"]==$phn  ||   $row["phn_no3"]==$phn)
{
    $formatted = "".substr($phn,6,10)." ";
    $password = $formatted + $adm;
    echo $password;
    $db->setpassword($adm,$password);
    $pre = 'PREFIX';
    $suf = '%20ThankYou';
    $sms = $pre.$password.$suf;
    session_start();



     $ch = curl_init("http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx? USERID=ID&PASSWORD=PASS&SENDERID=SID&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
     header("Location:password.php?msg=new"); 

    }
else
{
    header("Location:register.php?msg=invalid");

}
}
}
?>
```

this code is working perfect on my local host .. but when i put it on server ... it takes lots of time but the code in curl command is not working it only refers to next page ... i checked that curl is enabled .. if i use only sms api without curl command it sends sms immidiately.... but i want to run both header and also want to hide my sms api.... is there any alternate of this ???

Comment: I don't understand your question. If it's slow, can you tells us _what_ is slow? Also what part of the curl request isn't working?

Comment: if you put an `exit;` before the `header()` call, you should at least be able to see whether you get any error messages befor the redirect can take place. (You might have to use `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` at the start of your script in order to enable error messages). Then please post the error messages here, otherwise we can just guess and not really help you.

Comment: when i generate password on server it takes lots of time to go to password.php page but the sms api do not work than .. but on local host it takes 2 seconds and sms also send to user

Comment: ok let me check error message

Comment: please write exact code of      ini_set('display_errors', 1) with commas collons etc. ???

Comment: is there any alternate of curl ??

Comment: @ connum it is returning 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if simple wget or curl from server to SMS API working fine or not ?

bash~/$wget "http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx? USERID=ID&PASSWORD=PASS&SENDERID=SID&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms"

bash~/$curl "http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx? USERID=ID&PASSWORD=PASS&SENDERID=SID&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms"

If wget or curl is fine then something wrong with your code.

If wget or curl not working from server then might be port 80 is blocked by your ISP for outgoing traffic. Check with ISP for same.

Also you can try

telnet www.perfectbulksms.in 80

and see if its getting connected or not.

Comment: i'm not that good in coding please ...can you elaborate the code with semicolons of each and every line.. like how to start how to end >>> please